# Server-side validation example?/Java

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, server-side

I am trying to create a registration form that performs both client side and server side validation. I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate to perform this. I already have the client side figured out, but I'm confused on how to do server side validation? Is this even possible with what I'm trying to achieve?

I apologize if I don't make sense, I am a fairly new programmer. If more info is needed then please let me know.

Comment: Spring also provides @Validator annotation and BindingResult class through which we can get the errors raised by Validator implementation in the controller request handler method and also hibernate-validator make validation more easier.

Comment: Which level validation do you need and for what? Is it enough to have hibernate annotations for restrictions validations?

Comment: I have to validate things like name, email, phone number, address, city, country etc. Some have to be validated on client side while others on the server side if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hibernate Validator` can meet your requirements validating fields on the server-side.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "username cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 15)
    private String username;

    @Max(100)
    private int age;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @CreditCardNumber
    private String creditCardNumber;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```